# How do I use Blueprints?

Tags: starbound

I recently found an Energy Dash Blueprint deep underground.  I took it back up to my spaceship, but I can't figure out how to use it.  How do I use a blueprint?  I'm assuming it has something to do with the 3D Printer, but I can't figure out how to use the two together.

Comment: Try using it like you would use food. Pick it up and click anywhere.

Comment: @3ventic Not quite sure, then. That used up the recipes I tried it with, but added them to my crafting lists. Energy Dash is probably a different type.

Comment: No this is correct. Just 'use' it anywhere. The energy Dash is a tech that gets added to the Tech station on-board the ship (took me a while to find out where it went when I used it myself).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just 'use' it anywhere. The Energy Dash blueprint you have is a type of tech that gets added to the Tech station on-board the ship. Once you've unlocked tech, go to the tech station on your ship, select a tech on the left, then click one of the "lock-in" buttons on the right to equip that tech.

I don't think it tells you how to use it, but the Energy Dash is used by double tapping left or right for whichever direction you want to dash in.

When using other blueprints, such as furniture or weapons, a little pop-up at the bottom of the screen will say "Learned to craft new item" confirming usage. The recipe will then be available for crafting at the crafting station used to make that particular item.

Comment: Did I mention I was stuck on my spaceship for 5 minutes before realizing I had to press "e" to use anything?  

This is very helpful, thank you.

Comment: @Zibbobz Same here, haha, I was standing on the teleporter pad for a few minutes trying every possible key combination, before realizing I had to mouse over the teleporter.

Comment: I don't get it, I have several blueprints in my items. I cannot do anything with them. The tech section on my ship is empty. I'm particularly interested in the all-seeing helmet. But I cannot figure out how to use it.

Comment: Left-click to pick up the blue print then left-click again anywhere outside the inventory screen. same as you use any other item. You can also equip it on the hotbar.